# The user defined function returns error while i try to pass a reverse character algorithm through the function

Tags: arrays, c, linux, string, user-defined-functions

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char reverse(char num[]);
int main()
{
    char num[10], result;
    int len;
    printf("Enter the number: ");
    scanf("%s", num);
    result = reverse(num);
}
char reverse(char num[])
{
    int len;
    char rever;
    len = strlen(rever);
    for(int i = len -1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        printf("%c", num[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to pass the reverse string algorithm using an user defined function to execute it by calling it in the main code but, it returns some unknown error. Can anyone help by fixing the code.

Comment: `rever` is a single char (and not even initialized) and then you call `strlen(rever)`, but `strlen()` expects a nul-terminated string.

Comment: Please note that the "unknown error" exact text is probably [quite enlightening](https://godbolt.org/z/TadW636cd) and should be part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You didnt calculate the `strlen` properly inside your reverse function. Use this instead:

`int len = strlen(num);`

Also, you dont need the `rever` variable inside the function.

Furthermore, if you type a number of 10 characters or more you're gonna run into problems.